# How to parse inner json objects

Tags: json

I need to parse this json,can any one help me to do this?

```
{
   "his_data_bg":{
      "history":[
         {
            "date":"2016-10-06 11:00:00",
            "value":72,
            "dataID":"639F1006A8A4C9965E5E8E558138450A"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: with which language?

Answer (score 0):

i am using jackson

```
package parse;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"his_data_bg\":{\"history\":[{\"date\":\"2016-10-06 11:00:00\",\"value\":72,\"dataID\":\"639F1006A8A4C9965E5E8E558138450A\"}]}}";

        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

            System.out.println(node.get("his_data_bg").get("history"));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output : `[{"date":"2016-10-06 11:00:00","value":72,"dataID":"639F1006A8A4C9965E5E8E558138450A"}]`

i think it may help you